# i am having difficulty with this Inheritance Java Program

Tags: java

Employee Class

```
 public abstract class Employee
{
   //Class Constants
   public static final double MINIMUM_HOURLY_WAGE = 8.00;
   public static final int    MAX_HOURS_WORK_WEEK = 40;
   public static final int    MAX_HOURS_WORK_DAY  = 8;

   //Instance Variables
   private final String number;  //ID number
   private double payRate;       //Pay-rate

   //Constructor
   public Employee(double payRate)
   {
      this.number = newNumber();
      this.payRate = payRate;
   }

   //Parameter-less constructor ****   TEMPORARY   ****
   //TO BE DELETED when subclass constructors completed
   public Employee()
   {
      this(0.0);
   }

   //Accessor
   public String getNumber()
   {
      return this.number;
   }

   //Accessor
   public double getPayRate()
   {
      return this.payRate;
   }

   //For implementation in subclasses     
   public abstract double grossPay();

   //Override
   public String toString()
   {
      String category = this.getClass().getName();
      category = category.substring(0, category.indexOf("Employee"));

      return category + " " + super.toString();
   }

   //Override 
   public boolean equals(Object other)
   {
      return super.equals(other);
   }

   //Helper: Create unique Employee number in the form xxx-xx-xx
   private static String newNumber()
   {
      return "xxx-xx-xx";
   }
}
```

SalariedEmployee Class

```
public abstract class SalariedEmployee extends Employee
{
   public static final double MINIMUM_SALARY = 
                              Employee.MINIMUM_HOURLY_WAGE * 
                              Employee.MAX_HOURS_WORK_WEEK ;



   public SalariedEmployee()
   {
     payRate = MINIMUM_SALARY ;        
   }

   public abstract double grossPay();


}
```

The only problem i had with this class is its constructor because the instructions say to enforce a minimum salary constraint via its constructor but i so not what that means(i just someone to clarify for me)

HourlyWageEmployee Class

```
public abstract class HourlyWageEmployee extends Employee
{
   //Instance Variable
   private TimeCard hours;


   public HourlyWageEmployee()
   {
       super(MINIMUM_HOURLY_WAGE);
       hours = new TimeCard();

   }

    public TimeCard getHours() 
    {
        return hours;
    }

    public void setHours(TimeCard hours)
    {
        this.hours = hours;
    }



   public abstract double overtime();

   public double grossPay()
   {
      return (this.getPayRate()) + overtime();
   }
}
```

My issue with the class is the instance variable "hours" of type TimeCard i cannot figure how to use to retrieve the hours from the class TimeCard because in that class hours is an array. also since hours is an array i cannot compare it to payrate or include it in any calculations in the overtime and grosspay methods because they are two different types

note: the two sub classes have two of their own subclasses each and i would edit this question to include those and the TimeCard if necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `SalariedEmployee` use

```
public SalariedEmployee(double payRate)
{
  super(payRate < MINIMUM_SALARY ? MINIMUM_SALARY : payRate);
}
```

This way, if the `payRate` is less than the minimum salary, it is replaced by the minimum salary.

Comment: if i do that than the sub classes of SalariedEmployee will not compile because the constructors have no arguments

Answer (score 0):

SalariedEmployee can't access payRate because payRate is private on Employee.

you should change payRate to protected modifer

Comment: i don't think im allowed to do that because the majority of the employee was provided to us

Comment: so you should declare payRate as field on SalariedEmployee